# Flatten complex object on entity in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have following objects:

Entity:

```
public class MyEntity : NamedEntity
{
}

public abstract class NamedEntity : VersionedEntity
{
    public LocalizedText Name { get; set; }
}
```

Complex object (LocalizedText):

```
public class LocalizedText : ILocalized<string>
{
    protected LocalizedText()
    {
    }

    public LocalizedText(string en, string de = null, string fr = null)
    {
        En = en;
        De = de;
        Fr = fr;
    }

    public string En { get; set; }
    public string De { get; set; }
    public string Fr { get; set; }
}
```

With this, I get following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'LocalizedText' requires a primary key to be defined.'
```

I don't want to make an entity out of `LocalizedText`, but want it stored in the DB in columns of the MyEntity table, e.g. Name_EN, Name_DE and Name_FR.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The myEntity table has a primary key ?

Comment: Yes it does (Guid Id), I didn't show the entire entity model as it isn't relevant; we have NamedEntity -> VersionedEntity -> BaseEntity (which defines the Id)

Comment: Does LocalizedText has a primary key?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk No, it is a POCO. As mentioned above I would like to store it in the MyEntity table by having a dedicated column per language

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/#owned-entities-and-table-splitting

For the above code I've adapted my `DbContext` implementation with:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyEntity>()
               .OwnsOne(r => r.Name);
    }
```

Which results in following CREATE (irrelevant parts masked in [...]):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntity](
    [...]
    [Name_En] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name_De] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name_Fr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```